# iOS Automated Tests - XCTest vs Katalon

Tags: xcode-ui-testing, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

We are developing a Xamarin iOS app and we need to automate the test cases. There are two choices right now. 
1. Xcode UI Test
2. Katalon

Before choosing a tool, I want to know your personal experience or recommendations about the above tools.

Currently, we have only the iOS version. But in future, we might have to do this app for Android. Also, we need to compare the values which display in the App with the values in the database or desktop version of the App.

Another thing is, we need to run these tests in the cloud devices (Probably in Visual Studio App centre)

Answer (score 1):

Well, lets go through some specs of your two choices

***XCTest:***

```
positive points:

- native tool (but you obv don't care about native tools, since your app is in Xamarin)
- a lot of support from forums/Apple etc
- free
- easy to use, if you have native app
- easy to add to CI pipeline

negative points:

- no support for Android
- not supporting desktop-mobile comparison (it may be done with some 3rd party tools tho )
```

***Katalon***

```
positive points:

- supports iOS and Android (beware, that this does not mean, you can use the same code - you will still need to write two sets of methods etc, but Katalon can be used for Android, XCTest not)
- free - to some point (paid support)
- in theory supports the thing with mobile + web data comparison (not gonna be easy, but surely possible)  


negative points:

- not as much support - forums etc
- writing complicated methods is not very easy (but if you have app with a few views, than it will work well)
- implementation to CI is harder
```

You have to select, which solution suits you better, and though I am not a fan of 3rd party testing tolls (cuz its pain to set it up correctly etc), Katalon might be better for you in your scenario (iOS + Web + maybe Android).
Hope this helps you :-)